# how to resolve sqflite error : MissingPluginException sqflite

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I created my database with this function:

```dart
void CreateDatabase() async {
    database = await openDatabase(
        'todo.db',
        version: 1,
        onCreate: (database, version) {
            print('database is created ');
            database
                .execute(
                    'CREATE TABLE tasks(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , title TEXT, date TEXT , time TEXT , Status Text )')
                .then((value) {
                    print('table created');
                }).catchError((error) {
                print('error when creating table ${error.runtimeType}');
            });
        },
        onOpen: (database) {
            print('database is opned ');
        },
    );
}
```

Of course after installing dependencies in `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
    flutter:
        sdk: flutter 
    sqflite: ^1.3.0
```

Then, I called the function `CreateDatabase();` but this error appear:

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:41319/dart_sdk.js:5375:11)
    at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:41319/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:1551:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:41319/dart_sdk.js:39799:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:41319/dart_sdk.js:39656:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:41319/dart_sdk.js:34585:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:41319/dart_sdk.js:35170:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:41319/dart_sdk.js:35208:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:41319/dart_sdk.js:35050:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:41319/dart_sdk.js:35073:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:41319/dart_sdk.js:39961:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:41319/dart_sdk.js:39967:13)
    at http://localhost:41319/dart_sdk.js:35432:9
```

I called the function inside floating button:

```dart
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
        CreateDatabase();
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted),
    // fabIcon,
),
```

Did I miss any step in creating database?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `flutter clean` and `flutter build` should fix it.

That happens when the dependencies are not embedded in the binary.

Comment: should i use the command flutter build apk or bundle ?because it demand to add a subcommand

Comment: When developing `build apk`, when releasing/publishing, you can use the `bundle`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Status column type Text wrong, right status TEXT
```

**Maybe**

I change your code check your code